# C++ Function Return with && Operator

Tags: c++

I'm looking through a library, and I see this function:

```
bool CCAPI::IsConnected() const
{
    int state;
    int res = CCAPIGetConnectionStatus(&state);
    return (res == CCAPI_OK) && state;
}
```

Specifically, what does this last line mean? It looks to me like it's returning two variables as it's using the `&&` operator. So what's going on here?

Comment: What about the `&&` operator makes you think it's returning two values?

Comment: I looked at it the wong way thinking that `&&` means to return x AND x instead of evaluating a condition.

Comment: Please "Accept" the @CoryKramer answer if it has answered your question (as your comment on his answer seems to indicate)

Comment: Sorry i meant to do so a while ago but forgot about it due to the 10 minute wait

Comment: @Scrubbie: Please don't rush people into accepting answers. They are free to do so in their own time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is going to return a single `bool`, like the function says it will.

The operator `&&` is logical `AND`, so if `res == CCAPI_OK` and `state != 0` then it will return `true`. In this case `state` is being implicitly converted to `bool` for the `&&` operation.

Answer (score 0):

Operator `&&` is [Logical AND](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_logical), could be written as `and` too.

> The logical operators apply logic functions (NOT, AND, and inclusive
>   OR) to boolean arguments (or types contextually-convertible to bool),
>   with a boolean result.

So the last statement will return the operation result with type `bool`.